# Angularjs how to call function from another controller?

Tags: angularjs, web, angularjs-scope

I have checked some of the topics for this matter and i got an understanding of controllers are there to initiate scope and i need to use services for this matter but i dont know how.

so here is the problem. i have index page which body has only one div and inside the div i have ng-include listening to a function called viewFile() which is described on controllerA. on the first initial attempt i load a view called login.html and display it. when users logs in and its successful, which are handled in controllerB, i return a token and now i want to load main.html page using viewFile() in controllerA. is there a call back function or notify controller or something for this? or can i write a service that takes care of this for me?

I'm not using ngRoute because i dont want my URL to change to mysite.com/#/login.html and then mysite.com/#/main.html

```
.controlle("A", function ($scope, sharedVariable){
$scope.token = sharedVariable.getToken();
$scope.viewFile = function(){
if($scope.token == "")
   return "view/Login.html";
else
   return "view/main.html";
}
}
.controller("B", function ($scope, $http, sharedVariable)){
  http({
   get ...
   .success: function(data){
      $scope.token = sharedVariable.setToken();
      // INVOKE viewFile from above controller
   }
  })
}
```

and here is the index.html body part

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="A"><ng-include src="viewFile()"></ng-include></div>
</body>
```

Comment: So are you using full page postbacks then?

Comment: It's always better to have part of your code in your question , But , as far as I underestood.
You Want that when use log's in , you fire a function , and then show a view ? Am I right ? 
if so , tell me , I'll give you the right answer

Comment: yes you got it, i'm trying to post part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this simple example http://jsfiddle.net/derkoe/T85rg/presentation/ here personService.person is shared between two controllers similarly  you can write your viewFile  function in one service like personService. Then call personService.viewFile   from any controller. You can pass $scope  as its argumen. Something like below

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('myService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};


    sharedService.viewFile  = function($scope) {
        if($scope.token == "")
            return "view/Login.html";
        else
            return "view/main.html";
        };

    return sharedService;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the view using different condition define you viewFile function in some service or put it in routescope. Then you can call it from multiple controllers. But I don't think without refresh angularjs will be able to load a different view html

Comment: what i want to achieve here is just like creating a function called viewFile(), and when ever i call it, it change the content of some particular div. its easy in jquery, i'm just new in angularjs and i dont know how to call invoke a function in another controller